# How to proper Conditional Testing

Tags: cypress, cypress-conditional-testing

I just want to ask how to properly conditional testing? I have this code here

```js
    cy.get('[data-slug="add-to-any"] > .plugin-title > strong').then(($slug) => {
      if (expect($slug).not.to.exist){
         //It will passed
      }else if (expect($slug).to.exist){
        cy.get('#deactivate-add-to-any').should('not.exist')
      }
```

I assert the element to not.to.exist, but it gives me this error

> Expected to find element: [data-slug="add-to-any"] > .plugin-title > strong, but never found it.

I am really lost what assertions I need to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ideal way (if it works in your scenario) is to shift the last selector inside the `.then()`

```js
cy.get('[data-slug="add-to-any"] > .plugin-title')
  .then(($pluginTitle) => {

    const $slug = $pluginTitle.find('strong');  // this finds with jQuery 
                                                // which won't fail the test 
                                                // if not found

    if ($slug.length === 0) {  // not found

    } else {
      cy.get('#deactivate-add-to-any').should('not.exist')
    }
  })
```

It's not 100% fool-proof, if $slug is loaded asynchronously (say via fetch) it won't be there immediately and the test might pass when in fact the $slug turns up 100 ms after the test runs.

You need to understand the way the app works to really be sure.

---

Cypress docs show this pattern, using `<body>` as the "stable" element (always present after page load).

```js
cy.get('body').then($body => {
  const slug = $body.find('[data-slug="add-to-any"] > .plugin-title > strong')
  if ($slug.length) {
      ...
```

It's less than ideal because the page might have `<body>` but still be fetching elements inside it.

Best practice IMO is to try the **immediate parent** element of the conditional one. If that is also conditional, move up the element tree until you find an element that is stable/present at that point in you test.

Or add a guard condition that waits for page fetch to complete. A `cy.intercept()` is useful for that, or even just this

```js
cy.get('[data-slug="add-to-any"] > .plugin-title')
  .should('be.visible')            // retries until .plugin-title is showing
  .then(($pluginTitle) => {
    const $slug = $pluginTitle.find('strong')
    if ($slug.length === 0) {  
      ...
```

Comment: I tried this and it works. You just need to get the parent element to apply the conditional testing in the child elements. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Simple example

```
cy.get("body").then($body => {
    if ($body.find('[data-slug="add-to-any"] > .plugin-title').length > 0) {   
   
        cy.get('[data-slug="add-to-any"] > .plugin-title').then($title => {
          if ($title.is(':visible')){
            //you get here only if it EXISTS and is VISIBLE
          } 
        });
    } else {
       //you get here if the it DOESN'T EXIST
        cy.get('#deactivate-add-to-any').should('not.exist')
    }
});
```

Comment: This is also working same solution of Fody below. Thanks!